# How to properly use Cloud Functions into Angular component?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

I create a cloud functions on Firebase and I'm trying to do a POST method on it.
How am I supposed to trigger this function into an Angular component ?

Here is what I did:

```
  const url = 'my-cloud-function-url';
  const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

  params.set('id', this.id);

  this.http.post(url, params)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
       })
       .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
       });
```

So this code is working but the POST method doesn't take arguments in parameters. I know that I could change the url to add the argument in it but I'm pretty sure this is dirty method.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#enable-http-services

Briefly, 
create service which call http post/get function.
And when a component needs data, it would use the service like below :

sms.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const BASE_API_URL = 'http-url';
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class SmsService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

    sendSms(sms){
        return this.http.post(BASE_API_URL+'/sms/send', JSON.stringify(sms), httpOptions);
    }

}
```

common.container.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SmsService} from '../../services/sms.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-common',
    styleUrls: ['common.container.css'],
    templateUrl: 'common.container.html'
})

    export class CommonContainerComponent {

    public number;
    public smsMessage;

    constructor(public smsService: SmsService) {}

    sendSms(number, message) {

        const sms = {
            receiver : number,
            context : message
        };

        this.smsService.sendSms(sms).subscribe(
            results => {
                console.log('sendSms results : ', results);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('sendSms error : ', error);
            },
            () => {
                console.log('sendSms completed');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was searching for :D